# Cucumber/Calabash-iOS and Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cucumber, xamarin, calabash

I try to implement UI testing with the calabash-ios testing framework. I followed all the howtos, tutorials spread on the different sites (xamarin testcloud guide, on github for the calabash-ios framework, ...)

In my project folder I created the feature directory with `calabash-ios gen`

My project structure is like the following: (just some of the folder/file(s)

```
- Certificates
- Resources
- Solutions
- Source
|- B2.Device.Core.iOS
|- B2.Device.Service.iOS
|- B2.Device.iOS
 |- AppDelegate.cs
 |- B2.Device.iOS.csproj
 |- Info.plist
 |- MyFooViewController.cs
 |- MyBarViewController.cs
 |- bin
  |- iPhone
  |- iPhoneSimulator
   |- Debug
    |- *.dll
    |- B2DeviceiOS.app
    |- B2DeviceiOS.exe
 |- features
  |- my_first.freature
  |- step_definitions
   |- *.rb
  |- support
```

Calling `cucumber` inside `Source/B2.Device.iOS/` throws an exception:

```
Dannys-MacBook-Air:B2.Device.iOS dannyyy$ cucumber 
Feature: Running a test
  As an iOS developer
  I want to have a sample feature file
  So I can begin testing quickly

  Scenario: Example steps                            # features/my_first.feature:6
  Unable to find *.xcodeproj in /Users/dannyyy/Projects/BauPlusMobile/Trunk/Source/B2.Device/B2.Device.iOS (RuntimeError)
  /var/folders/6p/s4dwcb0x1yx9wjjk_51ds21r0000gn/T/Calabash-CA09BEA0-1735-4818-AB85-4874C6849183/Gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:61:in `derived_data_dir_for_project'
  /var/folders/6p/s4dwcb0x1yx9wjjk_51ds21r0000gn/T/Calabash-CA09BEA0-1735-4818-AB85-4874C6849183/Gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:153:in `app_bundle_or_raise'
  /var/folders/6p/s4dwcb0x1yx9wjjk_51ds21r0000gn/T/Calabash-CA09BEA0-1735-4818-AB85-4874C6849183/Gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:148:in `relaunch'
  /Users/dannyyy/Projects/BauPlusMobile/Trunk/Source/B2.Device/B2.Device.iOS/features/support/01_launch.rb:29:in `Before'
    Given I am on the Welcome Screen                 # features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb:1
    Then I swipe left                                # calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:237
    And I wait until I don't see "Please swipe left" # calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:168
    And take picture                                 # calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:232

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:6 # Scenario: Example steps

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (4 skipped)
0m1.043s
```

How it's possible to have a XCode project file if I'm developing with the Xamarin.iOS environment? I tried also to set the `DEVICE_BUNDLE_PATH=~/Projects/BauPlusMobile/Trunk/Source/B2.Device/B2.Device.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug`

But of course the same exception will be thrown!

All the video demos and screencasts I have seen were working with Xamarin.iOS environment but without this error.

The only way to get working the tests is calling `cucumber NO_LAUNCH=1` and starting the app within Xamarin Studio with debugger attached.

I hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of try and error I got the solution for my problem. I guess I'll solve the problem in general for users which are working with the Xamarin.iOS environment.

1. Change to your project folder which contains the `*.csproj`
   In my case `> cd ~/Projects/MyProject/Trunk/Source/B2.Device/B2.Device.iOS`
2. Generate the `features` directory
   `> calabash-ios gen`

   - If you haven't calabash-ios installed yet lets start
     `> sudo gem install calabash-cucumber`
3. Create `config` directory and change to it
   `> mkdir config`
   `> cd config`
4. Create a file called `cucumber.yml`
5. Put the following content into it (the profile name as well as the other environment variables could be changed to meet your need)

   ```
   # YAML Template
   ---
   ipad-sim: APP="~/Projects/MyProject/Trunk/Source/B2.Device/B2.Device.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/B2DeviceiOS.app" BUNDLE_ID="tld.domain.project" SDK_VERSION=6.1
   ```
6. Go back to your project directory and start your tests
   `> calabash-ios -p ipad-sim`